# Framing packets from a UDP stream in Tokio

Tags: rust, udp, rust-tokio

Consider this small server that listens to a UDP stream:

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let sock = UdpSocket::bind(address).await.unwrap();
    let mut frame = UdpFramed::new(sock, PacketCodec::new());
    loop {
        match frame.next().await {
            Some(Ok((packet, _addr))) => {
                println!("got packet: {}", packet);
            }
            _ => {}
        };
    }
}
```

`PacketCodec` attempts to convert the incoming byte stream to `Packet`s via a custom logic that searches for a well-known preamble, and then chunks each packet according to a predefined size:

```
pub struct PacketCodec {
    sync: bool,
}

impl PacketCodec {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self { sync: false }
    }
}

impl Decoder for PacketCodec {
    type Item = Packet;
    type Error = io::Error;

    fn decode(&mut self, buf: &mut BytesMut) -> Result<Option<Packet>, io::Error> {

        if !self.sync {
            if buf.len() > PACKET_LEN * 2 {
                let srchstr = String::from_utf8(buf).unwrap();
                match srchstr.find(PREAMBLE) {
                    Some(n) => {
                        let _junk = buf.split_to(n);
                        self.sync = true;
                    }
                    None => {
                        let _junk = buf.split_to(PACKET_LEN);
                        self.sync = false;
                    }
                };
            }
        }

        if self.sync {
            if buf.len() > PACKET_LEN {
                let bs = buf.split_to(PACKET_LEN);
                let packet = Packet::new(&bs);
                return Ok(Some(packet));
            }
        }

        buf.reserve(PACKET_LEN * 2);
        Ok(None)
    }
}
```

This code runs just fine but hangs after one iteration, when sync has already happened, it is waiting for the next packet, but the `buf` size never increases.

Since the decoder returns `Ok(None)` when the bytes stream is smaller than the packet size, I would expect the Tokio runtime to send more bytes the next iteration, yet it doesn't.

How should I handle the incoming bytes stream properly?

Answer (score 1):

Kudos to @eggyal for digging in and opening issue [4888](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/issues/4888)

Using that information, I'm currently using the following workaround by overriding the default `decode_eof` method and ensuring that it never returns an error even if the buffer is empty:

```
fn decode_eof(&mut self, buf: &mut BytesMut) -> Result<Option<Self::Item>, Self::Error> {
    match self.decode(buf)? {
        Some(frame) => Ok(Some(frame)),
        None => Ok(None),
    }
}
```

Further details on whether this is actually an upstream bug will probably be discussed in the Github issue.

Comment: Your method there is purely delegating to `decode`; fine if that's all you need, albeit one could simplify the implementation down to merely `self.decode(buf)`, but perhaps returning an `io::Error` if the result is `Ok(None)` and `buf.len() == buf.capacity()` would be more appropriate?

Comment: @eggyal again a very good point, for what I'm doing I can get away with the current impl of just delegating to decode(), but yes otherwise that's a great suggestion